# Xcode 4.5 info.plist

Tags: xcode4.5, info.plist

I am using Xcode 4.5 and trying to add keys to info.plist (using **Add Row** command from drop down list, or click on **Plus** button).

The problem is that the plist don't add any extra keys that I need. It updates just when I switch between tabs: summary and build settings. I mean when I add new row to plist it has to add it to itself, in my case it don't do it. I don't see any updates in runtime. Have you got the same issues?

I have attached file where I at. When I press this button nothing happen with my plist, but the plist should add new row (key that will be stored in xml) as I think.

[image]

I also have added [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7NLcB3nN_w&feature=youtu.be) how it works.

Comment: I don't understand.  Post some screenshots or something.

Comment: I've updated question with images. The main problem is that my plist don't response to my action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the app's `info.plist` which has a fixed set of supported values.

I think you need to add a custom plist to your Xcode project, which can hold whatever values you want.

Comment: will it work for example if i need to set key Set Status Bar Initially Hidden and turn it to NO.

Comment: Yeah I reckon so.  Just add a `bool` value.

Comment: and one more thing. I have used this file for a long time without any problem, but now these problems came.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is, but you shouldn't be storing your own stuff there.  If it's app settings you're after then use `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: sorry as I think we speak about different things. I don't need to storing data. I need to configure my system. for example set interface orientation, status bar, load icon file and many other things. I don't need table which will store my own keys.

Comment: i have been able change app's plist in the previous Xcode, but now I can't even add new key, because the button does not work.

Comment: Not sure much of that is stored in the `info.plist` (apart from orientation, which can be changed in the target summary tab if I remember correctly).

Comment: yes you are right. we can do it. but the summary tab don't offer for us to do everything what we want. in additional we can add some keys that will setup our system. But also the main thing what I have found - the keys is adding when we switch between tabs (if we taped on plus button before of course)

Comment: i also have added video. can you check it please

Comment: I don't think that's a bug; Xcode is stopping you from having more than one row with that key (short version string).  If you select a different (unused) key then it should allow the row to be added.

Comment: but if you can see this is just a runtime error. because after switching we can see more keys in plist. because in previous time i have added it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19522/discussion-between-matrosov-alexander-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to create your own drop down values you must create a definition structure, which is a type of Xcode Plugin. Here are two other discussions that explain it well.

[How does Apple make the info.plist display its "Information Property List"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321933/how-does-apple-make-the-info-plist-display-its-information-property-list)

[Can I create a custom plist structure definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428768/can-i-create-a-custom-plist-structure-definition)